# Accesing internal attributes for Widgets

Tags: android, android-layout

I know that I can access custom attributes on widgets like this when I'm creating custom widgets:

```
 TypedArray a = context.getTheme().obtainStyledAttributes(
                attributeSet,
                R.styleable.FormEditText,
                0, 0);
        try {
            leftIcon = a.getDrawable(R.styleable.FormEditText_leftIcon);
        } finally {
            a.recycle();
        }
```

But if I want to access `android:hint`, how could I refer to it when creating a new custom view?

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to access the existing `android:hint` attribute in your custom view, you simply have to create a new styleable and refer to the existing android atrribute:

attrs.xml:

```
<declare-styleable name="YourView">
    <attr name="android:hint" />
</declare-styleable>
```

In your customViews initialization you can get this attribute like this:

```
TypedArray a = getContext().obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.YourView);
CharSequence hint = a.getText(R.styleable.YourView_android_hint)
a.recycle();
```